# size support in elasticsearch _suggest

Tags: elasticsearch

by default elastisearch _suggest returns 5 suggestions matching the criteria.Is it possible to extend that to more than 5, atleast 10 suggestions.
I tried size just like in other queries and seeing below error. any thoughts?

`"reason": "[suggest] does not support [size]"`

Comment: May I know which suggestor your are using.If you use completion suggestor we have size parameter.By default it will show 5 suggestions.But we can increase size depending upon the requirements.

Comment: yes, I'm using completion suggester. How to increase the size?

Comment: Can you show your suggest query, please?

Comment: Did you use the _size_ inside _completion_ like this 
`curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/music/_suggest?pretty' -d '{
    "song-suggest" : {
        "text" : "n",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "suggest", "size":10
        }
    }
}'` ?.

Comment: Please try the Mohammed Mentioned query so that it is helpful for your request

Comment: @KARTHEEKGUMMALURI i had this same problem.  the completion suggester documentation could be more clear on this.